# AWS Cognito custom static claims for all users in user pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, authorization, amazon-cognito

### Context:

I am integrating AWS Cognito into an existing multi-tenant application with preconfigured tenant ids. I am currently trying to find a way to add a custom static claim to each user in a given user pool. The claim is the `tenant_id`. This claim would have the same immutable value for each user in a user pool.

### **Question:**

Is there a way to add a custom static claim like this for each user in a user pool?

### **Reason:**

I would like to provide a stateless way to interact with existing services that currently only know of the existing tenant_id.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found so far is by creating a lambda for the Pre Token Generation Lambda Trigger and create a crosswalk from Cognito app client id to the existing tenant_id. Then get the tenant_id from the id token in the existing stateless services.